# how to reformate the index column in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
     0            1
0   0.224960    -1.376689
1   0.059706    -1.330823
2   -0.133850   -1.251549
3   -0.234644   -1.190972
4   -0.281469   -1.156635
... ... ...
295 0.655912    -1.040209
296 0.618599    -1.068238
297 0.594964    -1.109484
298 0.578758    -1.151496
299 0.570207    -1.179523
```

I added the index as a column and then generate fake time from this column like that:

```
df['timestamp'] = df.index


# convert the column (it's a string) to datetime type
datetime_series = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# create datetime index passing the datetime series
datetime_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(datetime_series.values)

# set timestamp as datframe index
df=df.set_index('timestamp')

df
```

The result is:

```
                                0            1
timestamp       
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000   0.224960    -1.376689
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001   0.059706    -1.330823
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002   -0.133850   -1.251549
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003   -0.234644   -1.190972
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000004   -0.281469   -1.156635
... ... ...
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000295   0.655912    -1.040209
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000296   0.618599    -1.068238
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000297   0.594964    -1.109484
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000298   0.578758    -1.151496
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000299   0.570207    -1.179523
```

I want the timestamp to be like 1970-01-01 00:00:00 then 1970-01-01 00:00:01 and so on.

Comment: @toptalent your answer gives1970-01-01 00:00:00.0>9 in all the timestamp column

Comment: @toptalent still the same output: 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be correct answer.

```
d = { i:"1970-01-01 00:00:00.{:0>9}".format(i) for i in df.index}
df.index = pd.Series(df.index).replace(d)
```

Tested like following:

```
tem = pd.DataFrame({'0':[1,2,3,4,5],'1':[3,4,5,6,7]},columns=['0','1'])
d = {0:"asdf",1:"asdf",2:"sdfs",3:"sdfs",4:"sdfs"}
tem.index = pd.Series(tem.index).replace(d)
```

tem print:

```
   0  1
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
3  4  6
4  5  7
```

d print:

```
{0: 'asdf', 1: 'asdf', 2: 'sdfs', 3: 'sdfs', 4: 'sdfs'}
```

result tem print;

```
      0  1
asdf  1  3
asdf  2  4
sdfs  3  5
sdfs  4  6
sdfs  5  7
```